# SMTPClient sending limit of 50 emails when using third party vs drop folder

Tags: c#, email, smtp, smtpclient, mandrill

I have an application that needs to send out a lot of emails on occasion. Most of the time, it sends approx 30 emails. It has no problem with this. On occasion though (once per month), it needs to send more than 50 (hundreds, not thousands).

When testing using a local drop folder, the SMTP client works fine and I can see all emails land in my drop folder.

When testing using Mandrill (the actual ESP), MandrilL only seems to receive 50 emails. This is consistent always.

- Each email to be sent gets its own SMTPClient instance.
- I've tried processing the emails in parallel and sequentially. Both behave the same.
- Code that sends each individual email:

  ```
  private static void Send(MailMessage mail)
  {
      SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();    
      client.SendAsync(mail, null);
  }
  ```
- Each email has a single recipient.
- ESP (Mandrill) reputation is high and sending limit is 1453 per hour. This is barely dented.

Can you suggest where this limit of 50 is being imposed (SMTP config, ESP config, other) and how I can remove (or increase) it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all of the message bodies are the same, you can just add all of the recipients to the Bcc (Blind Carbon Copy - meaning that none of the recipients can see who else got the message)  list and send the message once and have it be sent to all 50+ recipients.

If they aren't the same, simply reuse the same connection to send those 50+ emails.

The problem is probably that your SMTP server throttles incoming connections to 50 per hour or some other window of time to discourage DDoS.

Just because the server allows 1453 messages per hour doesn't mean you can connect to it 1453 times per hour.

Comment: The messages are all different so need to be individual (though Mandrill does have a template feature). Your answer about connections is pretty close. I heard back from Mandrill support. They informed me that they impose an active connection limit of 50. Coincidence? I think not. I think your point about reusing the connection will do the trick.